# Ruby Print all Key Value pairs of a object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The grandchild_task in the code below has a lot of key value pairs. How can I print all the Key Value pairs?

```rb
miq_provision_request = prov.miq_provision_request

prov.miq_request_tasks.each do |miq_request_task|
  miq_request_task.miq_request_tasks.each do |grandchild_task|  
    next unless grandchild_task.options.has_key?(:testing)
    testing_value = grandchild_task.get_option(:testing)
    $evm.log('info', "testing_value is: #{testing_value} ")      
  end  
end
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't print anything.

```rb
grandchild_task.sort.each { |k, v| $evm.log("TESTING", "\t#{k}: #{v}")}
```

Comment: Try `grandchild_task.options.sort.each { ... }`

Comment: not sure what you mean by trying `grandchild_task.sort.each { |k, v| $evm.log("TESTING", "\t#{k}: #{v}")}`. Lots of things can be wrong (eg: what Stefan shared above, issue with the `$evm.log` etc.). Can you share more context of where you are logging. Also, I see an early break. Are you sure that the options has key `:testing`?